# Can I use sealer over recycled asphalt to retain it?

Tags: driveway, asphalt, gravel

[image]I have a section of recycled asphalt chips to the left of my concrete driveway, which we use parking a second car. The asphalt rocks leave a mess in the yard and in the driveway. Could I use asphalt sealer over top the gravel to form a more solid surface? I've thought about using some landscape edging to keep some of the gravel in place, but that may not be a permanent solution. Any ideas or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify "asphalt gravel"?  Is this an old, deteriorated asphalt strip, recycled asphalt chips, or gravel used to make asphalt?  What, if anything, has been done to create or repair the surface?

Comment: Sorry, I believe they are recycled asphalt chips (old road). Nothing has been done or added to the surface.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the surface (with something to scale) would be really helpful. If you can't edit the picture into your question, add the URL of a picture and someone will be along to edit it in.

Comment: Added a photo of the surface.

Comment: At my plant we have a huge pile of used asphalt, we have tried filling holes and then using a large torch (weed burner) reheating it and tamping. This really stinks and kind of worked, we added some fresh asphalt to the mix and heated it then it worked well but it is really messy and created a lot of smoke. We used a plate compactor to tamp the patches. The first ones that we did not add asphalt did not last with heavy equipment running over it but the others where we added the asphalt have held up.

Answer (score 2):

No. Sealer isn't nearly strong enough to support the tremendous tearing forces at play.

Instead, watch your local community sale websites for used or leftover concrete pavers. You want the heavy duty ones, which are about 2-1/2" thick. With a little patience and luck you should find a relatively inexpensive lot that will give you proper pavement for life. You could even use the recycled asphalt concrete as a base, with a little sand over the top to make leveling easier.

Answer (score 2):

My boyfriend has a driveway with a crushed run base, #57 stone topped on that, recycled pavement dust over that, with bagged asphalt for the top layer. He got it to fuse using 1 part gasoline* to 2 parts diesel fuel. It was sprinkled with a watering can, then packed with a tamper. After a week of 90 degrees, it finally cured. He then thinned down driveway sealer with water & sprinkled it again. He used a small push broom to even the sealer & edge the sides. He let it dry one day & rebrushed the surface. This removes the shiny random areas. After another day he packed it with a riding mower making sure most ridges & any protruding gravels are flat. He then waited 2 more days to final coat the top with black sand. The blacktop sealant takes longer to cure on a tar & gravel mix. (cold patch) It turned out nice, & on a hot day it self heals. Takes around a week before you can park a car on it. *FIRE HAZARD- Do not smoke or run engines around driveway until the gasoline evaporates!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pouring a sealant all over your rock will provide you with a blissful outcome. I can't say I have a real answer to your problem either.

Here are the problems I can see with a sealer topcoat:

- Obnoxiously sticky residue
- Residue has a good chance of staining your driveway
- How to stop if from flowing over to your yard and driveway
- Stickiness and residue stains can be problematic each time it gets warm

Here's a possible solution -- still using a sealant.
Use it as an bonding undercoat. I would take the top 1/2" layer off and spread a layer of sealant about 1/4"-3/8" thick and spread that 1/2" layer back down and tamp it down to make sure the sealant reaches the top of the layer and bonds it all the way through.

That's about the best I can think of at the moment.

Comment: You make some good points, but sealer doesn't remain sticky once it's dry. It's not that different from latex paint.

Comment: I suppose I just had a tar based sealer in mind. There is the type that looks kind of like paint when it's dried, but I don't think that type would do anything to keep it all together.